# App development for Shopify with Remix (Route problem)

Tags: shopify-app, remix

I create a Shopify App with the remix app template (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix).

If i fetch the api "/api.new.jsx" everything work with the following structure:
[First structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDXY0.png)

If i change the structure to:
[second structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9kbk.png)

Now i get 404 not found back from my fetch call.
How can i use folders for my api?

I checked the remix documentation.